# Add read and publish permission together to ParseFacebookUtils

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

Above is my code but i cant find out together usage, always gives error

> Cannot pass a publish or manage permission (publish_actions) to a request for read authorization

This is my Permission list

```
private Collection<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
permissions.add("public_profile");
permissions.add("email");
permissions.add("user_birthday");
permissions.add("publish_actions");
```

And this is login request

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(activity, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
@Override
public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException parseException) {

       if (parseUser == null) {

       } else {

       }
    }
});
```

How can i use this together?

Comment: why use both use only facebook login.. and get facebook user information and then login to parse according to user information.

Comment: I think you don't need use for both.

Comment: so, how i can publish photo ?

Comment: when you get all information from facebook then get facebook profile image also.

Comment: you want to publish or post to facebook in your app.

Comment: yeap, i want to publish an image

Answer (score 3):

After long hours, this is solution. You must behave twice login to facebook. Once is publish and other one is read permissions. If you need public profile data , just publish permission is enough but in my case i need birthday, email, etc.. So code is below;

These are my permissions lists;

```
Collection<String> readPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
readPermissions.add("public_profile");
readPermissions.add("email");
readPermissions.add("user_birthday");
Collection<String> publishPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
publishPermissions.add("publish_actions");
```

Firstly, I should login with readpermission

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(activity, readPermissions, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException parseException) {

            if (parseUser == null) {
                listener.onFailure(new UserCancelledFacebookLogin());
            } else {
                getPublishPermissions(parseUser);
            }
        }
    });
```

After this, here my "getPublishPermissions" method; FacebookRequestListener is my own listener , don't care/mind delete it.

```
public void getPublishPermissions(final ParseUser parseUser) {
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    // User succesfully login with all permissions
                    // After this with these json and ParseUser , you can save your user to Parse
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name,name,email,gender,birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException facebookException) {

        }
    });

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(activity, publishPermissions);
}
```

that's all folks =)

happy coding to everyone

Answer (score 0):

The error message means you should not request read and write permissions at the same time. Login with read permissions when the User enters your App, request write permission (`publish_actions`) only right before you post.

Use [`ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithPublishPermissionsInBackground`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFacebookUtils.html#logInWithPublishPermissionsInBackground%28Fragment,%20java.util.Collection,%20com.parse.LogInCallback%29) for that.

That error message is already well known, take a look at some other thread about it:

- [How to set permission "publish_actions" in LoginButton using facebook sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888465/how-to-set-permission-publish-actions-in-loginbutton-using-facebook-sdk)
- [Facebook, setReadPermissions and setPublishPermissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727842/facebook-setreadpermissions-and-setpublishpermissions)
- [facebook login Cannot pass a publish or manage permission (email) to a request for read authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153312/facebook-login-cannot-pass-a-publish-or-manage-permission-email-to-a-request-f)

Comment: So how can i add permission to this code (while posting) SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).setCaption(text).build();

        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(photo).build();

Comment: i´ve added a link. you have to authorize again, with the publish permission, right before you want to post the photo

Comment: "no success" is nothing we can work with, it´s the same as "it doesn´t work" - zero information ;)

Answer (score -1):

You need to do a POST request instead of a GET one. See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/scores/#publish

Sample:

```
  Bundle param = new Bundle();
param.putString("message", "picture caption");
param.putByteArray("picture", ImageBytes);
mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", param, "POST", new SampleUploadListener());
```

this is your answer check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168145/android-post-picture-to-facebook-wall)

Comment: so What is "ShareApi" ?

Comment: this is your requirement you want to publish image then in this way to publish your image in facebook..

Comment: actually, his problem is the login process (see error message), not the upload itself. also, the link to the scores api is not really relevant...

Comment: I have say login through facebook not parse. because if you login through parse then facebook not provided and information to user.

Comment: if you want to login through parse then check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748256/parse-login-through-facebook-api-4-0-in-android-studio/29865703#29865703

Comment: I use Parse login for Facebook Login than i get informations from facebook graph api request.